# How can redirect domain.tld/* but /subdir/ not in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

http://egeszseg.7ed.hu/ have the following .htacces content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/adat/ - [L,NC]
Redirect 302 / https://www.facebook.com/pages/Eg%C3%A9szs%C3%A9gsarok-eapo/121098704741203
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^egeszseg\.7ed\.hu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.egeszseg\.7ed\.hu$
RewriteRule ^/$ "https\:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/pages\/Eg\%C3\%A9szs\%C3\%A9gsarok\-eapo\/121098704741203" [R=301,L]
```

Tried to load files from `/adat/` directory, but redirect to the facebook's error page instead of loading file file allocated on server: http://egeszseg.7ed.hu/adat/miert-ellenzik-a-hatasos-termeszet-adta-gyogymodokat-itt-a-valasz.pdf

Please let me **understand** how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `Redirect` directive, and remove the leading slashes in your regex patterns:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^adat/ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^egeszseg\.7ed\.hu$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.egeszseg\.7ed\.hu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.facebook.com/pages/Eg%C3%A9szs%C3%A9gsarok-eapo/121098704741203 [R=301,L,NE]
```